# make failure from travis going from sudo to container build

Tags: travis-ci, datastax-php-driver

I have a project that relies on datastax php-driver:
https://github.com/datastax/php-driver

I have been using this drive successfully for PHP 5.6 and travis.
I wanted to switch to container build since the owners of the php-drive has managed to do so (also getting the built faster is a bonus).

I ran into the following error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/travis/build/company-project/git-repo-project/php-driver/ext':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
The command "./install.sh" failed and exited with 77 during .
```

The .travis.yml file looks like the following:

```
language: php
sudo: false
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libssl-dev
      - g++
      - make
      - cmake
      - clang

cache:
  ccache: true
  directories:
    - ${HOME}/dependencies

php:
  - 5.6

env:
  global:
    # Configure the .phpt tests to be Travis friendly
    - REPORT_EXIT_STATUS=1
    - TEST_PHP_ARGS="-q -s output.txt -g XFAIL,FAIL,BORK,WARN,LEAK,SKIP -x --show-diff"
    - PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
    # Indicate the cached dependencies directory
    - CACHED_DEPENDENCIES_DIRECTORY=${HOME}/dependencies
    # Add libuv source build for container based TravisCI
    - LIBUV_VERSION=1.8.0
    - LIBUV_ROOT_DIR=${CACHED_DEPENDENCIES_DIRECTORY}/libuv/${LIBUV_VERSION}
    - APP_ENV=travis

before_install:
  # Configure, build, install (or used cached libuv)
  - if [ ! -d "${LIBUV_ROOT_DIR}" ]; then
      pushd /tmp;
      wget -q http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v${LIBUV_VERSION}/libuv-v${LIBUV_VERSION}.tar.gz;
      tar xzf libuv-v${LIBUV_VERSION}.tar.gz;
      pushd /tmp/libuv-v${LIBUV_VERSION};
      sh autogen.sh;
      ./configure --prefix=${LIBUV_ROOT_DIR};
      make -j$(nproc) install;
      popd;
      popd;
    else echo "Using Cached libuv v${LIBUV_VERSION}. Dependency does not need to be re-compiled";
    fi
  - git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
  - cd php-driver
  - git submodule update --init
  - cd ext
  - ./install.sh
  - cd "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR"
  - echo "extension=cassandra.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
  # Install CCM
  - pip install --user ccm

install:
  - composer update -n

services:
  - mysql
  - cassandra

script:
  - vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Initially as packages, only the libssl-dev was need, but since it was a C compiler missing, I decided to check the datastax build guide and toss in some extra packages: http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/

The error remains unchanged. I know that the reason why datastax's driver passes the the travis build is due to the fact the make is compiled in their  c language, however I was able to successfully do the entire run through when I used to be in sudo and not container. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tried `cat`ting `config.log`?

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь where is the config.log in travis? I click on RAW LOG and it gives me the same output, a bit more detail per line but it still terminates the same spot

Comment: Dunno, all I can see is "See `config.log' for more details"

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь as i have mentioned, that is the end output that I got